# Is there a way to get a window's cursor icon that would be displayed if the cursor was in a specific position?

Tags: winapi, cursor, icons, mouse

In different applications in windows, the cursor icon can change depending on the position of the mouse. Is there a way to get what this icon will be given a mouse position and a specific window, even if that window is not the foreground window?

Comment: I can't think of a good way. The cursor is set in response to `WM_SETCURSOR` which doesn't carry positional information - the app has to query the cursor position itself. So you'd need some way of faking that, and then some way of trapping the app's call to `SetCursor()` in order to intercept the cursor it sets. Not simple.

Comment: You would have to physically move the mouse cursor to the desired coordinates with `SetCursorPos()`, then send `WM_SETCURSOR` to the `HWND` located at those coordinates, then call `GetCursorInfo()` to get the latest `HCURSOR`, then finally move the mouse back to its previous coordinates.

Comment: (and bring the window to the front if it's not already)

Comment: Lame. I was hoping there would be a better way, and I'll keep the question open in case there is, but I'll just do that in the meantime.